# Where to find correct Java docs?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, birt

I'm using a new set of Java tools that I'm not entirely familiar with, for Birt report writing.

They're discussed here:

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/designEngineAPI.php#concepts

Now normally the Oracle API site seems to have and explain everything I need, but I've been unable to locate anything Birt related there.

The most promising link I came up with through Google, and the above link was:

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/source/org.eclipse.birt.report.model/?hideattic=1&root=BIRT_Project

However I'm finding that page difficult in navigating. I couldn't seem to find the grid, label, image classes and methods, etc that were mentioned in the first page's example. Have I missed them or are they in one of those folders? Or can they be found on the Oracle site?

Additionally, I will be looking for a class that allows a JDBC to SQLite. I haven't looked yet, but if anyone can tell me ahead of time a good one to use that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link:

[BIRT Programmer's Reference](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?nav=/9_0)